# How to test a dropdown component in react using react testing library jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the dropdown component using react testing with jest,however, I did try to use a different approach but did not find any solution, can anyone please help ? Also if you can share how this is been achieved would be great.

Please see the code I have tried so far:

**Dropdown component**

```
 <div>
                <button data-testid="dropdownBtn" className="dropdownBtn" onClick={handleDropdownClick}>
                    {placeholder}
                    <span>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} />
                    </span>
                </button>
                {showDropdown && (
                    <div data-testid="dropdownItems" className="dropdownItems">
                        {options.map((option) => (
                            <Link data-testid="items" to={option.to} key={option.value}>
                                {option.label}
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
```

**Testing the component:**

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { BrowserLink, Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";

const testOptions = [
    { value: "item1", label: "item 1", to: "/about" },
    { value: "item1", label: "item 1", to: "/about" },
];
    it("handles dropdown click", async () => {
            render(<Dropdown placeholder="placeholder name" options={testOptions} />);
            const dropdwonBtn = screen.getByTestId("dropdownBtn");
            fireEvent.click(dropdwonBtn);
            expect(dropdwonBtn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
```

**The Error I am getting:**
[image: error Image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues with your test code:

1 - As the error message suggests, I believe you need to wrap your test component with BrowserRouter for the test to progress:
`render(<BrowserRouter><YourComponent/></BrowserRouter>);`

2 - I noticed your test assertion `expect(dropdwonBtn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` is incorrect. That is because `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` is an assertion for checking that a certain function has been called a certain amount of times, but you are asserting it on a element rather than a function (`dropdownBtn`) so that would fail your test as well. Instead, you want to check that after your click the dropdown menu has actually appeared and you can do that by asserting:

```
// after click event
const dropdownMenu = screen.getByTestId('dropdownItems');
expect(dropdownMenu).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: Hi @AviCohenNehemia Thanks for the answer, and the explanation it did as you suggested, had to change little bit as per my needs, but thanks a again

Comment: Glad I managed to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the previous answer, you can assert that the drop-down has been expanded or you can assert that the individual options are visible

[test-library to verify aria-expanded value as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262344/test-library-to-verify-aria-expanded-value-as-false)